# What CSS selector do I need here?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, selector

I've this code generated with php:

```
<li class="current"><li><a href="#">Page1</a></li></li>
<li><li><a href="#">Page2</a></li></li>
<li><li><a href="#">Page3</a></li></li>
<li><li><a href="#">Page4</a></li></li>
```

I want to add a css property to tag `a` inside to list with class `current`.

I've tried with `.li + li + a {property:attribute}` etc...

[image]

Any suggestions ?

////////////////////// Edit

Ok guys... We did nothing. I tried to simplify the code. Here is the whole code (generated by wordpress):

http://pastebin.com/GJ3zXd93

Comment: Why do you have li inside of li?

Comment: Please read carefully [this tutorial](http://www.learnjquery.org/newsletter/Tutorial-2-jquery-css-selectors-walkthrough.html), it would clarify all your doubts.

Comment: Your markup is incorrect. The inner LI is an orphan without a UL or OL as parent.

Comment: @techfoobar or `menu` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context)

Comment: @canon - Never used `menu` before. Tks for the info. :)

Comment: Just as a sidenote, the implementation of <menu> is changing in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
li.current li a
```

But most likely the double list items are a mistake, so you probably want to use this instead:

```
li.current a
```

Also, as a sidenote, the "." in the selector you wrote is trying to find elements with a class of "li", not a list item element.

With the recent update of your question:

I think I know what's going on here.  You probably have a widget generating the menu for you.  The call to the widget is inside a `ul` in your PHP.  The widget generates the menu inside a `div`.  You are probably also using arguments for the widget call to wrap each menu item inside an `li`.  Which would give you the structure you have:

```
<ul>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><li></li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ul>
```

To fix, find where you are calling the widget, and remove the `ul` that's wrapped around it.  Then remove the before and after arguments from the widget call.  That should give you this structure:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you should have an easier time styling the menu.

Comment: Don't works :-/ Here's the whole code: http://pastebin.com/GJ3zXd93 Can you help me ?

Comment: The HTML you are getting out of WordPress is extremely screwed up. Are you perhaps using a plugin to generate this code?  There shouldn't be a div inside a ul.  Maybe you can post the PHP that is generating this as well.

Comment: Hey, I just removed a `<li> pair and now I've <ul><li><a></a></li></ul>` instead of `<ul><li><li><a></a></li></li></ul>` and now works fine with `li.current-menu-item a {}`. So, problem solved :) Thanks for contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
.current a {}
```

(All links which are descendant of the `.current` element).

Comment: @vlady: In that case I misunderstood your problem. Consider rephrasing please.